# Sitecore 8.2 Autofac Dependency Injection Error Clarification

Tags: dependency-injection, sitecore, autofac, sitecore8, sitecore8.2

I'm getting an error below when trying to use the Autofac DI with Sitecore 8.2:

> The dependency resolver is of type
>   'Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.SitecoreDependencyResolver' but was expected
>   to be of type 'Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver'. It
>   also does not appear to be wrapped using DynamicProxy from the Castle
>   Project. This issue could be the result of a change in the
>   DynamicProxy implementation or the use of a different proxy library to
>   wrap the dependency resolver.

Any idea on:

1. Why such scenarios occurs?
2. What does above mean?
3. How to fix?

Comment: Which exact version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: Sitecore 8.2 it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Root of the issue

This happens because `AutofacDependencyResolver` is not MVC's current dependency resolver. Here's the description of how `AutofacDependencyResolver.Current` attempts to locate the current instance of itself:

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#using-the-current-autofac-dependencyresolver

So you need to set up `AutofacDependencyResolver` with MVC. Normally, you would just follow this guide:

http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html#quick-start

Although, that is what you are probably doing already. The problem is, at some point Sitecore will override the configured dependency resolver with its own, and that happens *after* `Application_Start` is executed. So `AutofacDependencyResolver` ends up not being used by MVC.

## How to fix

Follow this guide:

http://www.seanholmesby.com/safe-dependency-injection-for-mvc-and-webapi-within-sitecore/

The essence of it is that you'll need to create a custom dependency resolver which will use `AutofacDependencyResolver` first, and if a dependency is not found, it'll fall back to `SitecoreDependencyResolver`.

The dependency resolver should be configured as a processor in Sitecore's `initialize` pipeline, which will make sure that Sitecore's dependency resolver is already available.

You can find Autofac-specific examples in this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/sitecore-chained-dependency-resolver/tree/master/InversionOfControl.Autofac

## Overriding Autofac's dependency resolver accessor

If the above doesn't help, you can tell Autofac how to get the current resolver.

When you create the Autofac resolver, save that object in a variable, and once you register the chained resolver in MVC, use the method `AutofacDependencyResolver.SetAutofacDependencyResolverAccessor()`:

```cs
var autofacResolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(container);

IDependencyResolver chainedMvcResolver = new ChainedMvcResolver(
    autofacResolver,
    DependencyResolver.Current);

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(chainedMvcResolver);

AutofacDependencyResolver.SetAutofacDependencyResolverAccessor(() => autofacResolver);
```

Now Autofac won't try to look for its own resolver directly in `DependencyResolver.Current` or Castle's DynamicProxy. It will directly use the resolver object you provided.

Comment: Thanks Dmytro. I updated solution per gibhub. However I keep getting 404. Not sure what's the purpose of ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new AutofacControllerFactory(container));

Comment: @NilPun Ah, OK, well now the fix should be easy. Just never use `AutofacDependencyResolver.Current` ;-) Either use MVC's `DependencyResolver.Current`, or take your dependencies via constructor arguments, as you should when you use DI.

Comment: And yeah, with Sitecore 8.2, you don't need to replace the controller factory. That was only needed before Sitecore 8.1.

Comment: Thanks @Dmtro. I did solution wide search for 'AutofacDependencyResolver.Current', it's no where being used.

Comment: It's used inside Autofac internally. See my updated answer on how to fix it by using `AutofacDependencyResolver.SetAutofacDependencyResolverAccessor()`.